# How to force python 3.6 on MAC OSX

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode on OSX to start python development. I'm supposed to be using python 3.6.xxxx but when I use `python -V` i get 2.7.10

My path variable is

> bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/leonardo/.rbenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/leonardo/bin:/Users/leonardo/bin: No such file or directory

I also can't get `pylint` to work on VSCode because, when i try to install it, i complains that `pip` is unavailable...

what should i do?

Comment: Are you using the python extension for VScode? I'm guessing the path variable you're talking about it the Windows one?

Comment: @kabanus im actually using MAC OSX... i've updated the title... and yes, i've installed the extension for VSCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to do it by going on VS Code Command Pallete (Command+Shift+P) and using the command `Python: Select Interpreter` and chose 3.6